# Do I need a Gigabit router with a 95Mbps download and 95Mbps upload speed for my broadband connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, gigabit-ethernet

My Speedtest [results are here](http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/5911059946):

[image]

I have planned to connect my Laptop ethernet port to the router through a cable, and use other mobile devices using 802.11ac standard. My laptop Eethernet port is compatible with gigabit ethernet.

Given that I don’t expect that my broadband speeds would change do I need a gigabit router?

Comment: No you don't need a gigabit since you're just under 100 Mbps. You might see some increased consistency in speeds with a gigabit router though. Just since your connection can max out your bandwidth, assuming your connection speeds are 95 Mbps upload and download like you stated.

Comment: Is this speed test taken with a 100Mbps connection anywhere between the modem interface and PC running the speed test? If so, I would connect a gig ethernet and retest... Actually, I would just suggest a quality gigabit router with AC wireless if you currently have a 10/100 router.

Comment: What speed of connection are you paying for?  "Broadband" doesn't define the speed you should be getting.  Unless you have a gigabit internet connection you probably don't need a gigabit router.  Since you have ac wifi you must have a modern router, but your question can be answered if you would edit those two items (class of service from isp and current router model number) into your question.

Comment: To be clear: a speed test doesn't tell the speed you SHOULD be getting, it indicate the speed you ARE getting.